# Haskell how to append with custom data

Tags: haskell

I have a data declaration as below

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

Nil means empty list, otherwise it represent a non empty list

This custom data type obviously doesn't support `(:)`, how can I append 2 List together of this data type without `(++)`?

function type as below

```
append :: List a -> List a -> List a
```

I am starting off with something like this

```
app Nil xs = xs
app (Cons x xs) ys =
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This custom data type obviously doesn't support `(:)`

The `(:)` data constructor is here `Cons`, but `Cons` has the same effect on a `List a` as `(:)` has on `[a]` (or more canonical `[] a`). You thus already have a function where you can reprend a `List a`, with an `a`.

> How can I append 2 List together of this data type without `(++)`?

With recursion. In case the first list is exhausted you return the second list, in case the first list has a  `Cons … …`, you thus will need to return a `Cons` where the first item is the first item of the left list, and the tail of the result uses recursion on the tail of the first paramter. This will thus look like:

```
app :: List a -> List a -> List a
app Nil xs = xs
app (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x …
```

where I leave implementing the `…` as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

We can actually derive the function definition from the data definition and some common sense / some laws that `append` must abide by.

First, we have

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

append :: List a -> List a -> List a

--        Nil         Nil         Nil
--       Cons x xs   Cons y ys   Cons z zs
```

This means we can just enumerate all the possible 2 x 2 x 2 cases,

```
append Nil         Nil         = Nil
append Nil         Nil         = Cons z zs   where z = .... ; zs = ....
append Nil         (Cons y ys) = Nil
append Nil         (Cons y ys) = Cons z zs   where z = .... ; zs = ....
append (Cons x xs) Nil         = Nil
append (Cons x xs) Nil         = Cons z zs   where z = .... ; zs = ....
append (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Nil
append (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Cons z zs   where z = .... ; zs = ....
```

then remove those equations that make no sense outright, and complete those that do.

*The law of append* is simple and *self-evident* enough when written down in some pseudocode,

```
   append [x1,x2,....,xn] [y1,y2,....,ym] =
          [x1,x2,....,xn,  y1,y2,....,ym]
```

This is like saying almost nothing new at all.